# Find entries with at least 1 image

Tags: entries, image

How can I find entries with at least 1 image?

```
{% set category = craft.categories.group('storyCategories').slug(catSlug).first() %}

{% set params = {
  section : 'stories',
  order : 'postDate desc',
  relatedTo: category,
  limit : '4'
} %}
{% set stories = craft.entries(params).find() %}
```

I have this, but am not sure how to only get stories entries when the story has an image.

Comment: Do you put your images in relationfields or do you upload them via redactor? The first is really easy

Comment: The images are in as asset fields.  I've just realised I can do this:
{% set params = {
      section : 'stories',
      order : 'postDate desc',
      relatedTo: category,
      limit : '4',
      storyImage: ':notempty:'  
    } %}

Where "storyImage" is the field name of my image field.

Comment: Yes indeed. Would you mind adding that as an official answer and mark it as solved for future reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just realised I can do this:

```
{% set params = { section : 'stories', order : 'postDate desc', relatedTo: category, limit : '4', storyImage: ':notempty:' } %}
```

Where "storyImage" is the field name of my image field